# HashCode loop not looping through string, program will not terminate due to while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, hashcode

I need my program to loop through the while loop and ask the user for an infinite number of strings...until they input "Done." If the string they interred is not "Done" then it calculates the hash code value of the entire string and sorts it into the proper tier. Once the user inputs done, the program prints the tallies in each tier and which tier is the largest.

**My problem:** The program asks the user for a string, calculates the hash value of each *letter*, sorts those values into a tier, prints the tallies, prints which tier is largest. Then asks the user for another string and continues this process -> *program never terminates*.

**FYI:** I have taken the printing statements (after the for loop) out of the while loop, and I get a compile error: "Cannot Find Symbol" pointing to all of my "tier" variables. I think this means I need to declare them *outside* of the while loop, but if I do, then the same problem occurs because they are not declared *inside* the while loop.

**What I need the program to do:** Ask the user for a string, calculate hash code, tally where appropriate (into the appropriate tier). Continue this cycle until the user enters "Done" then the program prints the tallied values in each tier and finally, prints which tier is the largest.

### Example Output:

Enter a string: Foo
Enter a string: Done
Greater than or equal to 2,000,000,000: 0
1,500,000,000 to 1,999,999,999: 0
1,000,000,000 to 1,499,999,999: 0
500,000,000 to 999,999,999: 0
Less than or equal to 499,999,999: 1
The largest bucket is Less than or equal to 499,999,999 with a size of 1

**Also, I know there is an easier way to determine which tier is the largest (lines 64-109), but I cannot figure it out. We have not talked about arrays or anything like that in my class so I'm not sure how to simplify all of that using just if/else statements.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringHashCodeLoop {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String strEntered;

// Prompt user for a string, store string in "strEntered."
System.out.println("Enter a String:");
strEntered = sc.next();

// Perform a while loop as long as the entered string does not equal "Done."
while (!strEntered.equals("Done")) {    
    // Convert all letters in the string to lower case.
    strEntered = strEntered.toLowerCase();

    // Declare the integer "length" and set it equal to the length of the entered string, to be used in the for loop.
    int length = strEntered.length();
    // Initialize each tier/bucket value to 0 before performing calculations.
    int tier1,tier2,tier3,tier4,tier5;
    tier1 = 0;
    tier2 = 0;
    tier3 = 0;
    tier4 = 0;
    tier5 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int hashValue = 0;
        hashValue += strEntered.charAt(i) * Math.pow(31, length - 1 - i);

        // Sort the Hash Code for the entered string into its corresponding bucket.
        if (hashValue >= 2000000000) {
            tier1++;
        }
        else if ((1500000000 < hashValue) && (hashValue < 1999999999)) {
            tier2++;
        }
        else if ((1000000000 < hashValue) && (hashValue < 1499999999)) {
            tier3++;
        }
        else if ((500000000 < hashValue) && (hashValue < 999999999)) {
            tier4++;
        }
        else {
            tier5++;
        }
    } // end of for loop

    System.out.println("Enter a String:");
    strEntered = sc.next();
} // end of while loop

// Print the tallied totals of each bucket.
System.out.println("Greater than 2,000,000,000: " + tier1);
System.out.println("1,500,000,000 to 1,999,999,999: " + tier2);
System.out.println("1,000,000,000 to 1,499,999,999: " + tier3);
System.out.println("500,000,000 to 999,999,999: " + tier4);
System.out.println("Less than or equal to 499,999,999: " + tier5);

// Print which is the largest bucket and the total of its contents.
    if (tier1 > tier2 && tier1 > tier3 && tier1 > tier4 && tier1 > tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
    }
    else if (tier2 > tier1 && tier2 > tier3 && tier2 > tier4 && tier2 > tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is 1,500,000,000 to 1,999,999,999 with a size of " + tier2);
    }
    else if (tier3 > tier1 && tier3 > tier2 && tier3 > tier4 && tier3 > tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is 1,000,000,000 to 1,499,999,999 with a size of " + tier3);
    }
    else if (tier4 > tier1 && tier4 > tier2 && tier4 > tier3 && tier4 > tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is 500,000,000 to 999,999,999 with a size of " + tier4);
    }
    else if (tier5 > tier1 && tier5 > tier2 && tier5 > tier3 && tier5 > tier4) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Less than or equal to 499,999,999 with a size of " + tier5);
    }
    else if (tier1 == tier2) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
    }
    else if (tier1 == tier3) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
    }
    else if (tier1 == tier4) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
    }
    else if (tier1 == tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
    }
    else if (tier2 == tier3) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier2);
    }
    else if (tier2 == tier4) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier2);
    }
    else if (tier2 == tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier2);
    }
    else if (tier3 == tier4) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier3);
    }
    else if (tier3 == tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier3);
    }
    else if (tier4 == tier5) {
        System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier4);
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: move the 2nd line inside while loop -> strEntered = sc.next(); to just before  end of while loop : ie to before } // end of while loop line and things should be fine

Comment: btw, use equalsIgnorCase instead of equals when you are checking for user input Done. earlier you converted the String from Done to done by using toLowerCase and then comparing it with Done. that caused your problem

Comment: @balajikrishnan I changed my code to address your first comment. I'm not sure why you suggest I put the first "Enter a string" prompt inside of the loop - how would the loop check if the string does not equal "Done" if it the user had not entered a string, yet? Also, my assignment says ->The word "Done" (case sensitive) should not be counted in the ranges and is case sensitive.  Nevertheless you should not stop or ignore variations of the word, like "dONE", "DoNE", "done" <- Wouldn't using equalsIgnoreCase ignore those?

Comment: @balajikrishnan \*\* Wouldn't using equalsIgnoreCase ignore those variations and count them as strings, rather than the stop word for the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line

```
int tier1,tier2,tier3,tier4,tier5;
```

to before the while loop, the **copy** the lines

```
tier1 = 0;
…
tier5 = 0;
```

and paste it just after where you moved the `int tier1…` line (still above/outside of the while loop).

That will get rid of compiler errors and let your application run.

What's happening is because you use the tier variables in both the while and the if statements, you need to declare the variables in a scope that contains both. Declaring them in the while means *only* the while can see/use them. That's why you have to move that code out.

The reason you have to copy those initialization lines (all the "tier# = 0" lines), is since the variables are definitely used in the if no matter if the while runs at all (for instance, what if the user puts "Done" as the first input). However, if the while loop never runs, then tier1, etc. will all be uninitialized, and the ifs would fail.

That's why you have to give them some initial value. Zero works fine in this case.

The reason you only **copied** that code (leaving it also inside the while) is because you still need those values reset to zero each loop.

Hopefully this makes sense and helps.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much for the detailed response. Java syntax and all of these special rules (initializing, etc.) confuse me. I really appreciate your help so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringHashCodeLoop {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String strEntered;

// Prompt user for a string, store string in "strEntered."
System.out.println("Enter a String:");
strEntered = sc.next();

// Perform a while loop as long as the entered string does not equal "Done."
while (!strEntered.equals("Done")) {    
    // Convert all letters in the string to lower case.
    strEntered = strEntered.toLowerCase();

    // Declare the integer "length" and set it equal to the length of the entered string, to be used in the for loop.
    int length = strEntered.length();
    // Initialize each tier/bucket value to 0 before performing calculations.
    int tier1,tier2,tier3,tier4,tier5;
    tier1 = 0;
    tier2 = 0;
    tier3 = 0;
    tier4 = 0;
    tier5 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int hashValue = 0;
        hashValue += strEntered.charAt(i) * Math.pow(31, length - 1 - i);

        // Sort the Hash Code for the entered string into its corresponding bucket.
        if (hashValue >= 2000000000) {
            tier1++;
        }
        else if ((1500000000 < hashValue) && (hashValue < 1999999999)) {
            tier2++;
        }
        else if ((1000000000 < hashValue) && (hashValue < 1499999999)) {
            tier3++;
        }
        else if ((500000000 < hashValue) && (hashValue < 999999999)) {
            tier4++;
        }
        else {
            tier5++;
        }
    } // end of for loop

    System.out.println("Enter a String:");
    System.out.println("Greater than 2,000,000,000: " + tier1);
    System.out.println("1,500,000,000 to 1,999,999,999: " + tier2);
    System.out.println("1,000,000,000 to 1,499,999,999: " + tier3);
    System.out.println("500,000,000 to 999,999,999: " + tier4);
    System.out.println("Less than or equal to 499,999,999: " + tier5);

    // Print which is the largest bucket and the total of its contents.
        if (tier1 > tier2 && tier1 > tier3 && tier1 > tier4 && tier1 > tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
        }
        else if (tier2 > tier1 && tier2 > tier3 && tier2 > tier4 && tier2 > tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is 1,500,000,000 to 1,999,999,999 with a size of " + tier2);
        }
        else if (tier3 > tier1 && tier3 > tier2 && tier3 > tier4 && tier3 > tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is 1,000,000,000 to 1,499,999,999 with a size of " + tier3);
        }
        else if (tier4 > tier1 && tier4 > tier2 && tier4 > tier3 && tier4 > tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is 500,000,000 to 999,999,999 with a size of " + tier4);
        }
        else if (tier5 > tier1 && tier5 > tier2 && tier5 > tier3 && tier5 > tier4) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Less than or equal to 499,999,999 with a size of " + tier5);
        }
        else if (tier1 == tier2) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
        }
        else if (tier1 == tier3) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
        }
        else if (tier1 == tier4) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
        }
        else if (tier1 == tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier1);
        }
        else if (tier2 == tier3) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier2);
        }
        else if (tier2 == tier4) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier2);
        }
        else if (tier2 == tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier2);
        }
        else if (tier3 == tier4) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier3);
        }
        else if (tier3 == tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier3);
        }
        else if (tier4 == tier5) {
            System.out.println("The largest bucket is Greater than 2,000,000,000 with a size of " + tier4);
        }

    strEntered = sc.next();
} // end of while loop

// Print the tallied totals of each bucket.
}   
}
```

If you need user Input to be only Done then use equals method itself.

regarding moving the line:
what you initially did was got the input using strEntered = sc.next(); before while loop. check input -> equal to Done then proceed.

inside the while loop:
after scanning the next input, it was converted to lower case -> implying during the next iteration, it cannot possibly be 'Done' with a uppercase D in front. thats the reason i asked to move the scanning part to the very end of the while loop

Comment: This is the output I get when I run your program:    

Enter a String:    
boo    
Enter a String:    
Greater than 2,000,000,000: 0    
1,500,000,000 to 1,999,999,999: 0    
1,000,000,000 to 1,499,999,999: 0    
500,000,000 to 999,999,999: 0    
Less than or equal to 499,999,999: 3    
The largest bucket is Less than or equal to 499,999,999 with a size of 3
Enter a String:

Which leads me back to my "FYI" statement. If I end the loop just before I print all of the tallies, I get an error message "Cannot Find Symbol" pointing to all of my "tier" integers.

Comment: I did not mean to move the end of your while loop. i just said the move the strEntered = sc.next(); statement  alone to the end of the loop without modifying any other piece of code. Thats why I added the code that i said in this answer. Try running my code and you wont get the cannot find symbol error.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly and got the output shown above. After "the largest bucket is..." line, it prompts the user to enter a string again. Which is why I moved the end of the while loop above the println statements, that's when I get the compile error "Cannot Find Symbol."